# Descargar imagenes de un sitio con php y MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo varias imagenes guardadas en un sitio web

Ejemplo:

`$ruta = "https://misitio.com/imagenesGuardadas/";`

me contecto a la base de datos:

```
$conexion       = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

hago la consulta:
$query          = $conexion->query("SELECT f_uscis FROM links WHERE estado=3");
while($row      = $query->fetch_assoc()){
  $imagenes = $row['f_uscis'];//Obtengo los nombres de cada imagen
  print_r($imagenes);//me muestra el resultado de cada imagen
}
```

hasta aqui todo bien, el problema es el siguiente, ya intente descargar todos las imagenes, pero, solo me descarga una sola, alguien que me pueda yudar?
muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *descargar*? No veo ningún código donde intentes descargar algo. Por otra parte, ¿has verificado que hay más de una fila en tu tabla que cumpla el criterio de esa consulta SQL?

Comment: ¿qué tienen que ver las imágenes con la consulta que haces? ¿y qué tiene qué ver la consulta con el hecho que las quieras _descargar_?

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo en tu codigo es que es tu variable $imagenes se chanca con el valor extraido de $row['f_uscis'] en cada iteración.
Si quieres tener todos los valores, en este caso las imagenes, debes de guardarlos en un array:

```
$conexion       = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

hago la consulta:
$query          = $conexion->query("SELECT f_uscis FROM links WHERE estado=3");
$imagenes = array();
while($row      = $query->fetch_assoc()){
  $imagenes[] = $row['f_uscis'];//Obtengo los nombres de cada imagen
}
print_r($imagenes);//me muestra el resultado de todas las imagenes almacenadas
```